# Better proof for $x^3 + y^3 = (x+y)(x^2 - xy + y^2)$

Tags: alternative-proof

## Prove this $x^3 + y^3 = (x+y)(x^2 - xy + y^2)$

### My attempt

*Proof* - by using [axiomdistributive] and [axiommulcommutative]:
$$\begin{split}
    &(x+y)(x^2 - xy + y^2)\\
    &= (x+y)x^2 - (x+y)xy + (x+y)y^2\\
    &= (x^3+x^2y) - (x^2y+xy^2) + (xy^2+y^3)\\
    &= x^3 + x^2y - x^2y - xy^2 + xy^2 + y^3\\
    &= x^3 + y^3\\
\end{split}$$

Q.E.D.

### Question:

Spivak says there is an easy proof that, if I use this other theorem:

$$
x^3 - y^3 = (x-y)(x^2 + xy + y^2)
$$

then, I will also allow me to find out $x^n+y^n$ whenever $n$ is odd.

How to do this?  I fail to see how.

---

Comment: The $y$ in the second theorem need not be the same $y$ as in the identity to be proved.

Comment: Maybe juste change your $y$ by $-y$ and see what happens

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case of $n=3$ your result follows from this other theorem by considering $x^3+y^3=x^3-(-y)^3$. The pattern with odd $n$ is that $-y^n=(-y)^n$.

Comment: $x^3+y^3 = x^3 - (-y)^3 = \big(x - (-y)\big)(x^2 + x(-y) + (-y)^2) = (x + y)(x^2 - xy + y^2)$ --- is this the entire proof? :D

Comment: Looks good to me!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not easier, but given $$\frac{1-z^n}{1-z}=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}z^i\\1-z^n=(1-z)\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}z^i\\$$ let $z=\frac{y}{x}$, then $$1-\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^n=\left(1-\frac{y}{x}\right)\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}y^ix^{-i}$$ multiplying by $x^n$ yields $$x^n-y^n=(x-y)\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}y^ix^{n-1-i}$$

Answer (score 2):

$$x^3+y^3 = x^3+\color{red}{x^2y-x^2y}+y^3 $$
$$ = x^2(x+y)-y(x^2-y^2)$$
$$ = x^2(x+y)-y(x-y)(x+y)$$
$$ = (x+y)(x^2-y(x-y))$$
$$ = (x+y)(x^2-xy+y^2)$$

We can proceede similary for arbitrary odd $n$.

Answer (score 0):

Just let $k=-y$ to obtain $$x^3-y^3=(x-y)(x^2+xy+y^2)\iff x^3+k^3=(x+k)(x^2-xk+k^2)$$
Note that the same works whenever $n$ is odd. Given $$x^n-y^n=(x-y)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}y+\dots + xy^{n-2}+y^{n-1})$$
Let $k=-y$ and ...

See how it works? Try to explain why it doesn't work whenever $n$ is even!